# How to get more control and syncronization with Service?

Tags: android, android-service

Currently I'm developing an App which run a service. This service is not binded to any activity and even is launched alone(with no ui or activity) at the boot of the device.

This service setting makes really hard to have control of the service  or to have a good syncronization/communitcation with UI activities  when it is need.

So, Which are the best tools to have my service under control(know if is running, good communication with ui, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you are doing **inter-process** communication. You should refer to [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html), i.e. Android Interface Definition Language, which is for sure your friend.

Check below links for quick tutorials:

- http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/
- http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/48.html
- http://owenhuangtw.pixnet.net/blog/post/23760257-android-aidl-(android-interface-definition-language)
- http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/04/using-the-android-interface-definition-language-aidl-to-make-a-remote-procedure-call-rpc-in-android/

Another option is to consider using:

- [RemoveViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) and
- [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

RemoveViews describes a view hierarchy that can be displayed in **another process**. The hierarchy is inflated from a layout resource file, and this class provides some basic operations for modifying the content of the inflated hierarchy.

By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity).